# Prevent default is not working in my code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am developing wordpress website using php, I want to do 4 steps for single php file.If the condition is satisfied it will go to the next page.

```js
function checketudesandformations() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  if (x < 3) {
    alert("Please Select atleast 2 documents'");
    document.location.reload(true);
    return false;
  } else {
    //return true;
  }
```

If above the conditions is satisfied then only below the jquery want fire but i am getting button fire  the condition is not satisfied. So please help me any one

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#suivantsteps2").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery("#candidaturetabform2").css("display", "none");
      jQuery("#candidaturetabform3").css("page-break-before", "always");
      jQuery("#candidaturetabform3").css("display", "block");
      jQuery("#step03").addClass("active")
      jQuery("#step02").removeClass("active")

      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Below my HTML code

```
<form name="etudesandformations" id="etudesandformations" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#"  style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <input name="inesv6" type="hidden" value="">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td width="50%" align="right">
                       <input  class="saisie1 input"  name="precedent" id="precedent" type="submit" value="Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent" onClick="" tabindex="5">
                </td>
                 <td align="left">
                <input  class="saisie1 input" name="suivantsteps" id="suivantsteps2" type="submit" value="Suivant" onClick="checketudesandformations()" tabindex="4">
               </td>
              </tr>
           </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Even after Adiga's edits, I'm not be able to understand the question. How is `checketudesandformations` called? And how is that function related to the jQuery ready function?

Comment: You need to show the HTML code as well, along with what are you preventing by default in the form.

Comment: It makes no sense to have two separate "click" handlers here. Merge it all into one function, it will be easier to manage. Also...why are you reloading the whole page if the user didn't select at least 2 documents?? That is going to seriously annoy your users, if they have to re-enter all the data because of one mistake.

Comment: Oh and why are you using tables for layout? This is 1990s technology. Use CSS and divs / flexbox / something-else-modern-and-responsive to control the appearance of your page. Tables are verbose and inflexible, and are intended for displaying rows of data, not shaping a whole page - additionally it will confuse people using screen-readers etc if you do that.

Comment: I don't know how to merge that function, so please give some example code

Comment: "I don't know how to merge that function".... I'm not suggesting anything complicated. Start by taking all the code from `checketudesandformations` and pasting it into `jQuery("#suivantsteps2").click(function(e) {` in a suitable place (so that the code runs in the order you want it to). Then test it, and make sure it's working as you want.

Comment: Thanks ADyson It's working perfect, I thought both are different code like js and jquery so that i didn't merge

Comment: jQuery is made entirely using JavaScript - it just adds some functions to JavaScript which can make some tasks simpler. They are not separate languages! You can use "normal" javascript inside a jQuery function

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand question properly, but u need to rectify your code first. Use single event handler for onclick event as below. If you need more help please create atleast minimum working fiddle of your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checketudesandformations() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  if (x < 3) {
    alert("Please Select atleast 2 documents'");
    document.location.reload(true);

  } else {
    jQuery("#candidaturetabform2").css("display", "none");
      jQuery("#candidaturetabform3").css("page-break-before", "always");
      jQuery("#candidaturetabform3").css("display", "block");
      jQuery("#step03").addClass("active")
      jQuery("#step02").removeClass("active")
  }

</script>
```